# New to autoit, what is wrong with this variable?

Tags: mysql, autoit

so today I just started learning this language, and I'm trying to make my script with parts of example scripts from https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions.

I'm trying to run a mysql query and I'm getting "Variable Undeclared" error even if it declared as a Global one (atleast i think i declared it as one..)

Basically what my script should do is make an ID for every machine in my LAN store it into a txt file in AppData and then insert it into a db.

```
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>
#include <FileConstants.au3>
#include "EzMySql.au3"
#include <Array.au3>

Example()

Func Example()
   $id = Random(1, 1000, 1);Numar random de la 1 la 100
   Local Const $sFilePath = @AppDataDir & "\id.txt" ; Selectare %appdata% si id.txt
Local $iFileExists = FileExists($sFilePath)
    If $iFileExists Then

Else
    ; Create a temporary file to write data to.
    If Not FileCreate($sFilePath, $ID & @CRLF) Then Return MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "", "O eroare s-a produs in timp ce se scria fila temporara")

    ; Open the file for writing (append to the end of a file) and store the handle to a variable.
    Global $hFileOpen = FileOpen($sFilePath, $FO_APPEND)
    If $hFileOpen = -1 Then
        MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "", "O eroare s-a produs in timp ce se citea fila.")
        Return False
     EndIf

    ; Read the contents of the file using the handle returned by FileOpen.
    Global $sFileRead = FileRead($hFileOpen)
    ; Close the handle returned by FileOpen.
    FileClose($hFileOpen)

EndIf
EndFunc

; Create a file.
Func FileCreate($sFilePath, $sString)
    Local $bReturn = True ; Create a variable to store a boolean value.
    If FileExists($sFilePath) = 0 Then $bReturn = FileWrite($sFilePath, $sString) = 1 ; If FileWrite returned 1 this will be True otherwise False.
    Return $bReturn ; Return the boolean value of either True of False, depending on the return value of FileWrite.
 EndFunc   ;==>FileCreate

$name=@ComputerName
If Not _EzMySql_Startup() Then
    MsgBox(0, "Error Starting MySql", "Error: "& @error & @CR & "Error string: " & _EzMySql_ErrMsg())
    Exit
 EndIf

If Not _EzMySql_Open("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "vrgaming", "3306") Then
    MsgBox(0, "Error opening Database", "Error: "& @error & @CR & "Error string: " & _EzMySql_ErrMsg())
    Exit
 EndIf

If Not _EzMySql_Exec("INSERT INTO `lan` (id, nume) VALUES ('"& $sFileRead &"', '"& $name &"')") Then
    MsgBox(0, "Error opening Database", "Error: "& @error & @CR & "Error string: " & _EzMySql_ErrMsg())
    Exit
EndIf

_EzMySql_Close()
_EzMySql_ShutDown()
Exit
```

Comment: what's the whole error?

Comment: i want to insert $sFileRead in the "id" column in my table, but i get a "Undeclared variable" error, even if I actually declared it in the first function as a global one.

Comment: For what variable is this error being thrown?

Comment: $sFileRead this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of logic issues with the code, that makes it a little tricky to follow.

The error in this case is almost certainly caused because "id.txt" exists, and so `$iFileExists` evaluates to true, and the global variable is never created.

Then you are creating a new "id.txt", for writing, before reading all the data, so $sFileRead will always be blank and FileRead will set @error as you are trying to read from a file opened for writing.

Now, I think you want the $sFileRead to be whatever the contents of id.txt is, and id.txt should be created with a new random id if it doesn't exist. If so then you need to move the code that opens and reads the file outside of the `Else...Endif` block (in addition to changing FileOpen to use $FO_READ).

This answer doesn't address the questionable programming practice and code structure.